# Eclipse asking me to make this abstract?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract

I need to produce two separate jar files, both interact with each other but do different things. I have two projects loaded into Eclipse, but both use a lot of the same imports, and so I have them in subfolders under the same workspace.

One of them gets `"java class xxxx`could not be found" when I try to run it.

As I attempted to fix that, I was comparing the two projects and noticed that a folder was part of the external build path of the working one, but not the non-working one. I added it to the non-working one and broke the working one.

The one that had been working now has an error on the main class name. I call the program ZSTATEngine, and so the class is

```
public class ZSTATEngine implements ETOSFilterEngine
```

Now that name is highlighted and when I mouse over it is says:`"the type ZSTATEngine` must implement the inherited abstract method `ETOSFilterEngine.doFilter(MessageBlock)"`

What could have changed? It was working fine before, and nothing in the code itself changed. I don't understand how the referenced libraries work, but it at least appears nothing changed in their structure in the formerly-working project.

Ok some further information: I do actually have a section within that class:

```
public MessageBlock doFilter(MessageBlock msgBlock)
```

so I am implementing that method... but that method has an error inside of it now,

> "The method addFilteredMessage(MessageBlock) in the type FilterFramework is not applicable or the arguments (MessageBlock) ...

How could that have gone bad? It was working fine too.

Here's the full code:

```
package com.ibm.tpf.internal;

import java.awt.Color;  
/*import java.util.ArrayList;*/
/*import java.util.*;*/

import com.ibm.tpf.etos.TPFFilter.*;
//import com.ibm.tpf.etos.TPFFilter.TernarySwitch;

import com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.*;
/*
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.Constants;
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.MessageBlock;
*/
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.filter.*;
/*
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.filter.ETOSFilterEngine;
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.filter.FilterConfigurationException;
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.filter.FilterFramework;
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.filter.FilterRuntimeException;
*/

public class ZSTATEngine implements ETOSFilterEngine {
    FilterFramework fw = null;
    String[] names = null;

    public ZSTATEngine(FilterFramework filFW, String[] parms) {
        super();
        this.fw = filFW;
    }

    /* AAES0009I 13.45.01 FROM TA 05 : AUTC0000I TOSFCOLOR_GREEN TOSBCOLOR_NONE TOSHOLD_0 TOSSAVE_0 TOSALERT_0 AUTC1111I 12.04.41 OK */
    public MessageBlock doFilter(MessageBlock msgBlock) throws FilterRuntimeException {
        if(msgBlock.getMsgID().equals("AAES0009I")) { /* only handle messages that start with AAES0009I */
            if(msgBlock.getMsg().indexOf("ZUVRT") != -1) { /* if the message contains "ZUVRT" then let it through.  We want to react to the result of it, not the ZUVRT itself. */
                return msgBlock;
            }
            if(msgBlock.getMsg().indexOf("AUTC0000I") != -1) {        /* search string to see if "AUTC0000I is in it.  If it is then do..." */ 
                String myString = msgBlock.getMsg();
                Color fColor = Color.WHITE;                           /* set default colors */
                Color bColor = Color.BLACK;
                msgBlock.setSuppressed(TernarySwitch.ON);             /* suppress original message to display new one */
                String[] myStringParts = myString.split("\\s+",13);   /* divide message into 13 parts.  The 13th part is everything remaining. */
                String finalPart = myStringParts[12].toString();      /* print last part to the screen */
                MessageBlock mb = new MessageBlock(finalPart, Constants.ETOS_ONE_MSG);
                String fColorMsg     = myStringParts[7].toString();   /* Process the foreground color portion */
                if (!fColorMsg.contains("NONE")) {
                    fColor = ColorStringInterpreter(fColorMsg);
                    mb.setForeground(fColor);
                }
                String bColorMsg     = myStringParts[8].toString();   /* Process the background color portion */
                if (!bColorMsg.contains("NONE")) {
                    bColor = ColorStringInterpreter(bColorMsg);
                    mb.setBackground(bColor);
                }
                String holdMsg = myStringParts[9].toString();         /* Process the hold message portion */
                if (holdMsg.toUpperCase().startsWith("TOS")) {        /* if it starts with TOS, grab only the number at the end */
                    String[] holdPart = holdMsg.split("_",2);
                    if (holdPart[1].toString().equals("1")) {
                        mb.setHeld(TernarySwitch.ON);   
                    }   
                }
                else {
                    if (holdMsg.equals("1")) {                        /* otherwise, just use the number */
                        mb.setHeld(TernarySwitch.ON);   
                    }
                }
                String saveMsg = myStringParts[10].toString();        /* Process the save areas.  These have two formats currently: TOSSAVE_X_X_X_X and BBBBBBBBB, where X is a digit 1-32, and B is binary. */
                if (saveMsg.toUpperCase().startsWith("TOS")) {         
                    String[] savePart = saveMsg.split("_");           /* handle the multiple digit save areas, and ignore the first split which is TOSSAVE */
                    if (!savePart[1].toString().equals("0")) {
                        long areaBits = 0;
                        for (int i=1; i<savePart.length; i++) {
                            areaBits |= 1L << Integer.parseInt(savePart[i]);
                        }   
                        mb.setSave(areaBits);
                    }
                }
                else {                                               /* otherwise, just use the binary string directly */
                    long areaBits = Long.parseLong(myStringParts[10].toString(), 2);
                    mb.setSave(areaBits);
                }
                fw.addFilteredMessage(mb);                           /* this is the command that pieces the whole message together */
            }
        }
        int plusLocation = msgBlock.getMsg().lastIndexOf('+');
        if (plusLocation > 0) {
            MessageBlock mb1 = new MessageBlock(msgBlock.getMsg(), msgBlock.getFlag());
            fw.addFilteredMessage(mb1);
            msgBlock.setSuppressed(TernarySwitch.ON);
            MessageBlock mb2 = new MessageBlock("", Constants.ETOS_ONE_MSG);
            fw.addFilteredMessage(mb2);
        }
        return msgBlock;                                             /* whatever gets returned is what the system prints */
    }

    private Color ColorStringInterpreter(String colorMsg) throws FilterRuntimeException {
        if (colorMsg.toUpperCase().startsWith("TOS")) {              /* if it starts with TOS, then we're using color names */
            String[] colorParts = colorMsg.split("_",2);
            String colorTxt     = colorParts[1].toString().trim();
            if (colorTxt.toUpperCase() != "NONE") {
                Color finalColor = Colors.fromString(colorTxt);
                return finalColor;
            }
        }
        else {
            String[] colorParts = colorMsg.split("_",3);            /* otherwise we're using RGB values */
            String sRed = colorParts[0].toString().trim();
            String sGreen = colorParts[1].toString().trim();
            String sBlue = colorParts[2].toString().trim();
            /*mb = new MessageBlock(sRed, Constants.ETOS_ONE_MSG);*/
            int iRed = Integer.parseInt(sRed);
            int iGreen = Integer.parseInt(sGreen);
            int iBlue = Integer.parseInt(sBlue);
            Color finalColor = new Color (iRed, iGreen, iBlue);
            return finalColor;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    public void modifyState(Object[] newParams) throws FilterConfigurationException, FilterRuntimeException {
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return false;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the original question to add more info

Comment: Your diatribe is getting in the way of understanding your issue

Comment: Perhaps you have two versions of the ETOSFilterEngine and after the change the Eclipse is linking to another version.

Comment: Maybe your code hadn't change, but it could be that you updated the referenced library  which contains that interface `ETOSFilterEngine` ?!

Comment: Did you try your project in another IDE? If it works on another IDE but not in Eclipse, then you can be certain the root cause is from Eclipse's settings.

Comment: Do you have your own class named MessageBlock?

Comment: I do.  Just updated the question.

Comment: Get rid of your own MessageBlock class, and instead use the one that is part of your library, or one that extends the library class.

Comment: That would work to solve the error, yes, but would be catastrophically bad for getting my program to work again.

Comment: OK, but it's your choice if you want to get rid of "Eclipse's" (actually Java's) error message or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS mentioned by "Jakub Zaverka" perhaps you have two versions in classpath or build path. Check the jar order, whether is picking the right class... It will happen even if no code has changed.

One way to find it out is, just do an F3 on ETOSFilterEngine and click "Link with editor" option in package explorer. It will show the .class file and the jar from which its picked up.. If its from the wrong jar or old jar, just go to Project>Properties>Build Path>Order and Export  and change the order of the right jar to the top, by clicking on Top button..

Comment: That did it!  Thank you for actually listening to what I was saying and figuring out what was going wrong with it.  I simply reordered the jar to the top and all the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ZSTATEngine implements ETOSFilterEngine
```

According to above code, your class  ZSTATEngine is implementing an interface ETOSFilterEngine, which means your class need to implement all the abstract methods of ETOSFilterEngine.

From [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html):

> Interfaces form a contract between the class and the outside world,
>   and this contract is enforced at build time by the compiler. If your
>   class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that
>   interface must appear in its source code before the class will
>   successfully compile.

Check the link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.9/com.ibm.tpfops.doc_1112/aaeo1/fengapi.html?cp=SSB23S_1.1.0.9%2F2-3-10-3

Below are the 5 methods  that are present in ETOSFilterEngine, which you need to implement.

```
public MessageBlock doFilter (MessageBlock) throws
          FilterRuntimeException;
     public void modifyState (Object[ ]) throws
          FilterConfigurationException,
          FilterRuntimeException;
     public boolean isActive();
     public void shutdown();
     public String getName();
```

*Above link has a code example on how to properly implement this interface. You can see that the class ZSTATEngine in the example is implementing all the 5 methods provided by ETOSFilterEngine.*

> Check the type of MessageBlock in your imports, it should be import
>   com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.MessageBlock; I can see that you have commented your import which is wrong.
>
> Uncomment the line : import com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.MessageBlock;

Comment: That may be true, but... it worked fine before this, and the code didn't change.

Comment: Uncomment this line : "import com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.MessageBlock;"

Comment: I am importing com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.*, which should grab it.